# How to send a hardcoded datetime value as input to stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

This may sound easy but I've tried several times yet couldn't get what I want.

I have a stored procedure that has an input which is of `DATETIME` type. I've made sure the stored procedure works by providing hardcoded string as such `N'2012-12-31 16:45:00'`.

Now I want to execute the same stored procedure with the same input value from C#. How should I specify the value of `Datetime`?

Restriction Updated: parameterized SQL are not allowed

Comment: How are you invoking your stored procedure?

Comment: did you tried it yourself?? what problem you really faced??

Comment: By a method that accepting `datetime` value. I've tried other datatype and all works fine

Comment: Note that I'm not suggesting adding parameterized SQL itself - I'm just suggesting using parameters when calling the existing stored procedure. The proc will already be declaring the parameters - you just need to provide values for them...

Answer (score 9):

(Answer written before the restriction against parameterized SQL was added.)

> How should I specify the value of Datetime?

With parameterized SQL, just like other values.

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("StoredProcName", connection))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Foo", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
        new DateTime(2012, 12, 31, 16, 45, 0);
    // Execute here
}
```

Don't mess around trying to find the appropriate string form. Avoid string conversions wherever you can. While I wouldn't be *too* averse to including hard-coded string and numeric values in straight SQL statements where they were suitably obvious, I'd definitely use parameters for any date/time values to avoid even a whiff of conversion problems. (And I'd use parameters for any string which *might* need to be escaped, too...)

Comment: Possibly with a `dateTime = new DateTime(2012, 12, 31, 16, 45, 0)` to set up the "hard-coded" `DateTime` values

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to implement that. The way they invoke the stored procedure is by calling the method and passing the value from variable such as `callSP(int number_1, int number_2)` and so I can simply test by `callSP(100,100)` and the stored procedure will be executed perfectly

Comment: now the difference is this callSP is accepting `DateTime` instead of `int`. I tried `''2012-12-31 16:45:00''` but it's giving me `Too many character in character literal`

Comment: @IsaacLem: Who is "they" here? It sounds like there's important context you're not telling us. You should just be able to specify the stored procedure name and then the parameters *as parameters* rather than directly in the call.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I do understand all the best practices but I have to comply with the existing coding standard which in my case, the previous developers doesn't implement the way as you pointed

Comment: @IsaacLem: I don't see why that would stop you from using parameters. If the existing "coding standard" is to invite SQL injection attacks, you should fix it. And if you knew about parameters but couldn't use them for some odd reason, you should have stated that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just supply a datetime as a parameter to the stored procedure.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnString"))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Exec SP_Test @theDate",conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("theDate",new DateTime(2012,12,31,16,45,0));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You could also add the hardcoded value as the default parameter in the stored procedure while you're testing.

Comment: @marc_s: Micro-optimizing how long the connection will be open for is really pointless IMO. How long do you think it takes to set a parameter? I doubt you would ever see this make a difference in any real-world scenario.

Comment: @marc_s: You probably missed the EXEC in my SQL command. It works just fine without cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure.